# Hide Row from dev gridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress

I want to remove/hide this row (in orange) from the grid, I don't know what this row mean.[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that the root node? I'm not familiar with devexpress but it looks like this is a root node and if you click on the down triangle it will collapse the child nodes. You are probably using a Group By in your data expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the [auto filter row](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1428) feature is enabled on you screenshot. This feature row allows data to be filtered on the fly - by typing text within a row.

To disable this feature set the [GridOptionsView.ShowAutoFilterRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsView_ShowAutoFilterRowtopic) property to `false`.

You can also restrict this option from activating by end-user via hiding the "Show Auto Filter Row" check item within the [Column Header Context Menu](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument556). To do this, just set the [GridOptionsMenu.ShowAutoFilterRowItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsMenu_ShowAutoFilterRowItemtopic) property to `false`.